# couch_potato : no such file to load -- json/add/rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I 'require' the couch_potato gem, I get the following error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- json/add/rails
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/couch_potato-0.5.7/lib/couch_potato.rb:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

I'm not particularly experienced with Ruby yet so took a shotgun type approach and uninstalled all my gems, then reinstalled starting with couch_potato. The json gem is a requirement so the latest version was installed automatically. But this issue has persisted.

I thought maybe this part of rails (because 'rails' is in the error ... it seems like a long shot but as mentioned I'm very new to Ruby and not completely sure how gems work yet :)) but the install ended abruptly after the following few lines (these are the last few lines after a very long list):

```
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-ssl-1.3.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rdoc-3.9.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for railties-3.1.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.18...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.0...
file 'lib' not found
```

But anyway I went looking for the missing file. In the gem folder (/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.9) there is 'lib' then 'json/add' which is a minor victory, but there is no 'rails' file in there.

At this point I checked my laptop ... there is an older version of 'json', but the file 'json/add/rails' does exist in that older gem.

What is my best option at this point? Is there a different version of couch_potato I should be using? Can I make couch_potato use the older json gem version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the JSON gem.

```
$ gem install json
```

Actually, the `json/add/rails` file is deprecated by the JSON library

```
# This file used to implementations of rails custom objects for
# serialisation/deserialisation and is obsoleted now.

unless defined?(::JSON::JSON_LOADED) and ::JSON::JSON_LOADED
  require 'json'
end

$DEBUG and warn "required json/add/rails which is obsolete now!"
```

but it seems couch_potato has not been updated and the require is still in place.

Comment: The json gem is already installed ... Yeah it seems like you are right with that being deprecated.

Comment: I just installed JSON 1.6.0 and the rails file no longer exists. You can force your project to require a version < 1.6.0 where the file still exists (even if deprecated). This is pretty simple if you use Bundler. Otherwise you can fork the `couch_potato` repository and fix the issue temporary, waiting for them to fix the issue. You might want to open a ticket on the `couch_potato` issue tracker.

Comment: thank you for putting in the effort, it is much appreciated :-)